# Comet, Ajax Push, Reverse Ajax

Tags: ajax, asp.net-ajax, comet, server-push, reverse-ajax

Someone have any sample of Comet app .net? 
I need one sample how to persist connection of client in server?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here are some good ones too:

http://www.frozenmountain.com/websync/demos

Answer (score 5):

Here are two nice and scalabe examples:

- [example 1](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/CometAsync.aspx)
- [example 2](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/SandBox_CometSample.aspx)

**Update**

Be sure to take a look at [SignalR](http://signalr.net/)

Answer (score 4):

There are many sample projects for ASP.NET [HERE](http://pokein.codeplex.com)