# C#/ASP Based Reverse AJAX

Tags: c#, asp.net, comet, reverse-ajax

I have a current project running using [APE](http://www.ape-project.org) that needs to work on C#/.NET... I was wondering if anyone had any suggestions for either a method of approaching Reverse AJAX/Comet on C#/.NET or any packages such as APE that are available.

### EDIT

For clarification, APE doesn't work on Windows. Which is a restriction I have with the project.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Comet, Ajax Push, Reverse Ajax](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2601893/comet-ajax-push-reverse-ajax)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that you asking for something like

http://www.frozenmountain.com/websync/

or

http://www.aaronlerch.com/blog/2007/07/08/creating-comet-applications-with-aspnet/

This is called [comet technique](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_(programming)) and is a web application model in which a long-held HTTP request allows a web server to push data to a browser, without the browser explicitly requesting it.

Answer (score 4):

[PokeIn](http://pokein.com) comet ajax library works platform independent. ( Mono + .Net )

Comment: the best thing with this library is the extra functionalities.